# send multiple bundles at once

Tags: android, android-activity, bundle

im trying to send two bundles at once from one activity to another and im having no luck.. i can send a bundle ok but when i try two send two i get a null pointer.
heres my code:

```
Activity A,
         @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    //  TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.label2);
        TextView number1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.label);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, options_Page.class);
    //  Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();
        Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
        bundle1.putString("title", number1.getText().toString());
    //  bundle2.putString("title2", name.getText().toString());
        i.putExtras(bundle1);
    //  i.putExtras(bundle2);
        startActivity(i);

Activity B,
                    Bundle bundle1 = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    //  Bundle bundle2 = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        String title = bundle1.getString("title");
    //  String title2 = bundle2.getString("title2");
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvnumber)).setText(title);
    //  ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvname)).setText(title2);
```

using this code as it is now it sends one bundle (number) no problem, if anyone knows how i can send the other (name) it would really help me. 
Thanks in advance...

Comment: im not sure if a need two bundles, i have to name and number on one activty in a list , that i need to send to another activity. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `send more then one bundle` but for your need from current scenario you don't need it, Just use one,

Try this, there is no need to 2 bundle,

In activity A,

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this, options_Page.class);
    i.putExtras("title", number1.getText().toString());
    i.putExtras("number", number2.getText().toString()); 
    startActivity(i);
```

In activity B,

```
    String value1 = getIntent().getExtras("title");
    String value2 = getIntent().getExtras("number");
```

or

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras == null) {
        return;
    }
    String value1 = extras.getString("title");
    String value2 = extras.getString("number");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First you don't need to pass two bundle but for your question I checked it at my end and you `can pass 2 or more than 2 bundle`.

you need to extract the bundle value like this:

```
Bundle bundle1 = getIntent().getBundleExtra("bun1");
boolean value1 = bundle1.getBoolean("value1");
Bundle bundle2 = getIntent().getBundleExtra("bun2");
boolean value2 = bundle2.getBoolean("value2");
```

Answer (score 0):

In `kotlin` you can send multiple bundles from `ActivityA` to `ActivityB` like this:

#### **ActivityA.kt**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val intent = Intent(this, ActivityB::class.java)
    val bundle1 = Bundle()
    val bundle2 = Bundle()

    bundle1.putInt(EXTRA_PHONE, 123)
    bundle2.putInt(EXTRA_PHONE, 456)
        
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_BUNDLE_1, bundle1)
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_BUNDLE_2, bundle2)
}
companion object {
    const val EXTRA_BUNDLE_1 = "EXTRA_BUNDLE_1"
    const val EXTRA_BUNDLE_2 = "EXTRA_BUNDLE_2"

    const val EXTRA_PHONE = "EXTRA_PHONE"
}
```

#### **ActivityB.kt**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val bundle1 = intent.getBundleExtra(ActivityA.EXTRA_BUNDLE_1)
    val bundle2 = intent.getBundleExtra(ActivityA.EXTRA_BUNDLE_2)

    println(bundle1?.getInt(ActivityA.EXTRA_PHONE))//123
    println(bundle2?.getInt(ActivityA.EXTRA_PHONE))//456
}
```